# Non standard complex analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, nonstandard-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding what should mean analytic for hypercomplex functions.
In deed I'm studying a book (Non standard analysis in practice by Diener) where they just say that the function is analytic (and not S-analytic) without defining it. That should not be a translation of the usual complex differentiability in non standard words because acording to the book this definition doesn't imply S-continuity.
I'm really confused so if anyone could help me ,that would be nice :)

Comment: Most likely the term means that the function is given locally by a convergent power series. This has an obvious translation in the nonstandard setting.

Comment: Could it mean $( f(z + \epsilon)-f(z))/\epsilon$ and $(f(z + \varepsilon)-f(z))/\varepsilon$ are infinitessimally close for any two infinitessimals $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$?

Comment: That one of my other problem, I can'y really see how to extend power series to the non standard universe. Should the indices and powers be non standard integers?

Comment: @Daron I don't think so because that would imply S-continuity... That's a really weird notion!

Comment: By *analytic* at $c$ they surely mean the usual definition of a derivative $L$, namely for every epsilon there is a delta such that if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen Diener's book but here are a few remarks that might be helpful. There is a difference between *continuity* at a point and *S-continuity* at a point. Here $f$ is said to be continuous at $c$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ necessarily produces $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. Meanwhile $f$ is said to be *S-continuous* at $c$ if $x\approx c$ necessarily produces $f(x)\approx f(c)$.  Here $a\approx b$ is the relation of infinite closeness, i.e., $a-b$ is infinitesimal.

Now if $c$ is a real point then the two definitions are equivalent.  However for general hyperreal $c$ they are not necessarily equivalent. For example the squaring function $y=x^2$ is continuous at all points including infinite ones according to the above definition of continuity.  However it is not *S-continuous* at an infinite point $c=H$ as can be easily checked.

In fact one can use *S-continuity* to give a *local* definition of uniform continuity of a real function on a real domain.

This distinction should help understand the complex-function issue as well.

By *analytic* at $c$ they surely mean the usual definition of a derivative $L$, namely for every epsilon there is a delta such that if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If I get it right with this definition of analytic the function should be continuous but not always S-continuous. Not really sure about this but the function `$ sin(x/\epsilon ) $`  where epsilon is an infinitesimal should be analytic but not S-continuous at any appreciable hypercomplex?

Comment: And an other question, in your definition do you ask the derivative L at x to be limited?

Comment: The function you mentioned is not the natural extension of a real function, so you shouldn't worry about it. As I mentioned the squaring function is continuous in the sense I explained, but not S-continuous at an infinite point, so you don't have to look very far to find such examples. Of course this does not happen at a real point.

Comment: Does $L=2H$ satisfy the definition with epsilon, delta for the squaring function at an infinite point $H$?

Comment: Ok so the derivative could be unlimited. Thank you a lot for  your help :)